# Why can not select "mp3" file in Crosswalk?

Tags: javascript, cordova, input, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I built an app using Cordova and Crosswalk, the version are

```
cordova -v
6.0.0

"name": "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview",
"version": "1.6.1",
```

In my app I used two input tags to select files:

```
<input type='file' accept='.mp3'/> 
<input type='file' accept='.lrc'/>
```

First issue is that the accept attribute does not work in Crosstalk.
Second issue is serious, the app crashes when selected a Mp3 file.
Selecting lrc file is OK.
Any advice is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific frameworks you're using, but as a guess - is it correct to have those `>`s in the middle of your input elements? That isn't valid in most markup I'm familiar with.

Comment: Sorry, it was my type miss.

Comment: So that typo isn't present in your actual code? It still doesn't work with that corrected?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work. It crashes when I select a .mp3 or .jpg file, but It doesn't crash when I select a .lrc file.

Answer (score 1):

The reason .mp3 files are not playing with crosswalk is because .mp3 is proprietary and so is not built into the cordova version of crosswalk by default. You can create a custom build for crosswalk by accepting the ELUA during the build process but I haven't worked out how to do that for cordova as of yet. Information on creating a custom build with .mp3 is found here 
[Enable MultiMedia in Crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Enable-MultiMedia-in-Crosswalk)